# How to convert date day per day in R into date month per month in numeric format

Tags: r, date

I have a lot of dates on R, for example :

```
18/03/2020
19/03/2020
20/03/2020
21/03/2020
      .
      .
01/04/2020
02/04/2020
03/04/2020
04/04/2020
```

And I have date from 18/03/2020 into 09/11/2021

My aim is to do a PCA on R. Then, I would like to transform all these date into numeric to use it.

I would like to have month per month and not day per day.

For example :

```
202003
202004
202005
.
.
.
202111
```

I need to have my individu as numeric to use function PCA

Thanks for reading me

Comment: How exactly are you trying to convert them? You have 8 example dates but only 4 example numbers—what's the relationship between 19/03/2020 and 202004? I'm also not sure that this will be a valid way to use dates for PCA, because you'll be assuming months are of uniform length, which they aren't

Comment: You'll also be counting on an inaccurate scale, basically like a base 12 but treated like base 10. For example, if 01/11/2020 is 202011, 01/12/2020 is 202012, and 01/01/2021 is 202101, then you're going up by 1 from November 2020 to December 2020 but up by 89 from December 2020 to January 2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is in `%d/%m/%Y`, we may convert to `Date` class first and then do the `format`ting

```
format(as.Date(df1$date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y%m")
```

Or another option is a regex

```
sub("^../(..)/(....)", "\\2\\1", df1$date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert dates with the `format()` function.

```
> Sys.Date()  # origin Date
[1] "2021-12-23"
> format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m") # date in YYYYMM
[1] "202112"
```

**Update:**

As you need it as numeric

```
as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m"))
```